# Check if a function exists from a bash script

Tags: bash, function

How can I determine if a function is already defined in a bash script?

I am trying to make my .bash_login script portable between systems, so I want to add logic to only call a function if it exists.

I want to add `__git_ps1()` to `PS1` only if that function exists on that system. This function normally defined in `git-completion.bash` which comes with git source, or by one of the bash completion scripts that ports/apt installs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if type __git_ps1 | grep -q '^function$' 2>/dev/null; then
    PS1=whatever
fi
```

Comment: Using `type` was much faster than `declare` -- thanks.

Comment: This is almost correct, but it will also return "true" if `__get_ps1` is an alias, builtin, etc. Use `if type -t function_name | grep -q "^function$" ; then ... fi`, to make sure `__git_ps1` is a function.

Comment: There is no reason to `grep`; just run `type` which returns true/false if the type exists or not. And, really, it doesn't matter if you use `type -t` or not; if the (standard) `__git_ps1` is defined, then that's probably what you want to use for your PS1 prompt, regardless of how it's defined; i.e., `if type __git_ps1 > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then PS1='\n\w $(__git_ps1)\n\!$ '; fi`

Comment: Do not use this. Depending on the language of the user the word "function" may not exist.

Answer (score 21):

I realize this is an old question, but none of the other answers do this quite as simply as I'd like. This uses `type -t` (as suggested in a comment by Chen Levy) as an efficient type-of test, but then uses shell string comparison rather than invoking grep.

```
if [ "$(type -t somefunc)" = 'function' ]; then
    somefunc arg1 arg2
fi
```

And to take it a step further, it also works indirectly:

```
funcname=do_it_special_$somehow
if [ "$(type -t $funcname)" != 'function' ]; then
    funcname=do_it_normal
fi
$funcname arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I really like this solution, though feel like the backticks in the string feel awkward. Regardless, I will certainly use this.

Comment: @csexton You can use `"$(type -t somefunc)"` instead of backticks.

Comment: Do not use this. Depending on the language of the user the word "function" may not exist.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg Citation needed. [Bash docs list specific strings for `-t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type), without any mention of localization.

Comment: Ah you are right. The `-t` should always be provided. This should fix the problem regardless of localization. Meaning this is the only correct way. Or looking at the exit code.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using:

```
type function_name
```

in will return your a function definition in case it exists. So you can check whenever output is empty or not.

PS. Even better I've just checked it will output that function is not exist otherwise output function body.

Comment: I would advice to use the `-t` option to avoid localization issues.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a `/bin/sh` compliant version, you can not use `typeset` or `declare` to test for a function definition as it is not a shell builtin. Also the `-f` option to `type` might not be available on some systems.

The solution I present is partly covered in other answers already:

```
isFunction() {
  type $1 | head -1 | egrep "^$1.*function\$" >/dev/null 2>&1;
  return;
}

isFunction __git_ps1 && PS1=__git_ps1
```

Answer (score 5):

declare -F 'function_name'  > /dev/null

echo $?

$? result has value 0 if the function exists, 1 otherwise

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to use declare, even if it is slightly slower than type. Type suceeds also for aliases or scripts that are in the PATH.

I am using this:

```
function function_exists
{
    FUNCTION_NAME=$1

    [ -z "$FUNCTION_NAME" ] && return 1

    declare -F "$FUNCTION_NAME" > /dev/null 2>&1

    return $?
}
```

So later in my scripts I can easily see what's going on:

```
if function_exists __git_ps1
then
    PS1=__git_ps1
fi
```

Or even the still readable one-liner:

```
function_exists __git_ps1 && PS1=__git_ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may list all available functions or check individual functions with compgen:

```
help compgen

compgen -A function

compgen -A function myfunc 1>/dev/null && echo 'myfunc already exists' || exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if declare -F | grep __git_ps1$
then
    PS1=whatever
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, busybox (minimalist all in one shell implementation, useful on Windows for example) has "type" but "type -t" prints the wrong thing, so I just check the return value of type to see if something is callable.  busybox also does not have declare.